# .htaccess authentication w/ friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, friendly-url

I'm trying to setup my .htaccess file to enable basic authentication on our development website.

I want the authentication to work on all my site but for certain URL. We are using friendly URL on our site..

I would also like to bypass authentication for certain file types like png, css, etc...

What I have so far looks like this :

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/upload/ NO_AUTH
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy  any
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=NO_AUTH
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|swf)$">
    Satisfy Any
</FilesMatch>
```

The authentication is working fine, but the `SetEnvIfNoCase` does not seem to work because I'm still asked for authentication when going to the friendly URL '/upload/'.
The `FilesMatch` part does not seem to work either ..

Anyone can help me with that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 things you need to address.

1. Your `<FilesMatch>` container is doing nothing. You already have a `Satisfy Any`. You should add those extensions to a separate `SetEnvIfNoCase`
2. When you are using rewrite rules that rewrite `/upload/`, you need to include **both** the "friendly" URI *as well as* the rewritten URI, because the auth module is applied *at every step* (obviously, since it's really really bad to allow bypassing of authentication by rewrite/alias). That means, for example, if you have this rule:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^upload/(.*)$ /upload_script.php?file=$1 [L]
   ```

Then you need to have a NO_AUTH line for **both** `/upload/` and `/upload_script.php`:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/upload/ NO_AUTH
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/upload_script.php NO_AUTH
```

Then to address #1:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|swf)$ NO_AUTH
```

---

So an example of the suggestion:

> something that you can try is to add a rule (similar to the above `RewriteRule` example), to route the `/upload/` to an intermediate script other than `index.php`, then from the intermediate script, call `index.php`.

So using the above example of `/upload_script.php` you'd add this **before** any of your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^upload/ /upload_script.php [L]
```

So that it looks something like:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^upload/ /upload_script.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Then, you create a script called `upload_script.php` which will have something like:

```
<?php
  include_once "index.php";
?>
```

You may want to dump the `$_SERVER['']` array first to see if everything's set to what Zend's `index.php` is expecting to see.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I addressed the #1 with your suggestion but I have a problem for the #2 because I'm using Zend Framework, I would have to allow my bootstrap "index.php" which would remove all the authentication. Do you have another suggestion for this ? By the way I cannot upvote your answer because I do not have enough reputation :/

Comment: @Jeff I'm not all that familiar with Zend or your setup, but something that you can try is to add a rule (similar to the above `RewriteRule` example, to route the `/upload/` to an intermediate script other than `index.php`, then from the intermediate script, call `index.php`.

Comment: I'm confused on how to make that work since I already have some `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`. I currently have the following code :  
`RewriteEngine On`  
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]`  
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]` 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` 
`RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]`  
`RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`  

Do you think you can enlighten me on how I can mix up your suggestion with that code ?